# Promise test timing out even after returning promise

Tags: javascript, node.js, mocha.js

I researched and found out that when testing promises in mocha, you have to return the promise.

I tried to do the following but the test keeps timing out. What the correct way to do this?

```
describe('A promise', () => {

    it('should not timeout', () => {

        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            setTimeout(() => {
                resolve('hi!');
            }, 3000);
        }).then((msg) => {
            expect(msg).to.equal('hi!');
        });

    });

});
```

Output:

```
$ ./node_modules/mocha/bin/mocha test.js


  A promise
    1) should not timeout


  0 passing (2s)
  1 failing

  1) A promise
       should not timeout:
     Error: Timeout of 2000ms exceeded. For async tests and hooks, ensure "done()" is called; if returning a Promise, ensure it resolves.
```

**Edit**: I tried adding the `done` in the `it` line and calling it in my `then` block but it doesn't work

Comment: Aren't you missing a `done` parameter inside the `it` callback?

Comment: Are you using [tag:jasmine] as well?

Comment: Just mocha and chai

Comment: This is obvious now. Change your `setTimeout` to 1000ms.

Comment: Mocha has a default timeout of 2s per unit test, for tests that are expected to run beyond this you need to extend the timeout...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this (only change: ".timeout(5000)" was added to "it"). This works for me. Basically you have to change the default timeout of 2sec for async call - if you expect your async call will take more than 2sec.

```
describe('A promise', () => {
    it('should not timeout', () => {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            setTimeout(() => {
                resolve('hi!');
            }, 3000);
        }).then((msg) => {
            expect(msg).to.equal('hi!');
        });
    }).timeout(5000);
});
```

2nd option (no need to change test in this case) :

```
./node_modules/mocha/bin/mocha --timeout 5000 test-mocha-spec.js
```

Answer (score 0):

Does this work ?

```
it('should not timeout', done => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        setTimeout(() => {
            resolve('hi!');
        }, 1000);
    }).then((msg) => {
        expect(msg).to.equal('hi!');
        done();
    });
});
```

Comment: Yeah, I could but this is not ideal. In my real test, I have no idea how long the test would take.

Comment: @Krimson Investigate time travelling. To test the api for real responses you shouldn't rely on a mocha test

Comment: `Timeout of 2000ms exceeded.` So change your `setTimeout` to 1000.

Comment: @Icepickle why not? What if I'm doing an integration test or e2e test?

Comment: Increase mocha's default timeout to 15000ms or your own expected timeout and consider failing when your tests raises it.

Comment: @Striped Setting the timeout makes the test brittle. I don't think its ideal. If a test fails out of a 1000 in a deployment pipeline just because it timed out, it is not really the best solution

Comment: So just consider the test failing with the 2000ms default timeout of mocha.

Comment: @Krimson because there are better frameworks to handle api responses? I am not saying you can't, I am only saying there are better possibilities for such tests (eg SoapUI, postman and other api frameworks)

Comment: You don't need `done` but you do need to either set a timeout less than mocha's `2000` default or extend mochas timeout. The original code is OK -- it is just that you chose a timeout longer than mocha is willing to wait.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to add the done parameter in the callback

```
it('should not timeout', (done) => {
```

and call it at the end,

```
}).then((msg) => {
    expect(msg).to.equal('hi!');
    done()
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You have 3 options:

1. return a promise
2. use done (if you also return promise error will be
   thrown)
3. use async/await

In all these cases you have to set timeout threshold, because mocha can't be sure will you resolve your async call or not. It is a protection from endless tests.

Usually, you need to fake you promised calls with some immediately resolved promise with some fake value, so you will not have such problems.